# count the value under the statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I am counting the value of `self.channel_count` to output them in each time when I pass on each statement to counting on the value.

Here is the output of the values that I am counting when I get pass on the statement in each time:

```
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program has finished
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 0
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program is half way
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 1
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3029
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3285
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3669
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3797
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program has finished
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 2
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program is half way
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 3
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program is half way
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 4
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program has finished
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 5
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: program has finished
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 6
```

Here is the full code:

```
self.program_remaining = False
self.channel_count = 0


for channel in channels:
    #get the stop_date data from the programs list
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channel])
    stop_date = cur.fetchone()


    if stop_date is not None:
       start_date = str(stop_date[0])
       stop_date = str(stop_date[1])
       get_current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
       get_start_time = time.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
       start_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_start_time)
       get_stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
       stop_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_stop_time)
       current_time = str(get_current_time)

       if current_time == start_time:
           print "the program has started"


       elif start_time < current_time < stop_time:
           print "program is half way"
           currenttime = self.parseDateTimeToMinutesSinceEpoch(start_date)
           program_stop = self.parseDateTimeToMinutesSinceEpoch(stop_date)
           program_stop - currenttime
           datetime.timedelta(0, 8100)
           current_program_length = program_stop - currenttime
           print self.channel_count

           if current_program_length >= 30:
              if self.program_remaining == True:
                 self.program_remaining = False
                 program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
                 progId = list()
                 posX = list()
                 posY = list()

                 for elem in program_button:
                     progId.append(elem.getId())
                     posX.append(elem.getX())
                     posY.append(elem.getY())
                 progId = map(str, progId)
                 posX = map(str, posX)
                 posY = map(str, posY)

                 for posX, posY, progId in zip (posX, posY, progId):
                     if int(posX) == 375:
                         print progId


           elif start_time <> current_time <> stop_time:
               print "program has finished"
               print self.channel_count

           self.channel_count += 1
```

I am trying to find out how I could get the value `self.channel_count` under the `elif start_time < current_time < stop_time:` to output the value under the `if current_program_length >= 30:` so I could get the results like this.

```
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 1
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 3
15:36:47 T:5080  NOTICE: 4
```

I tried to use this:

```
elif start_time < current_time < stop_time:
    ...etc
    print self.channel_count

    if current_program_length >= 30:
        for elem in program_button:
            progId.append(elem.getId())
            posX.append(elem.getX())
            posY.append(elem.getY())
         progId = map(str, progId)
         posX = map(str, posX)
         posY = map(str, posY)

         for posX, posY, progId in zip (posX, posY, progId):
             if int(posX) == 375:
                print progId
```

I will get the results like this:

```
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program has finished
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program is half way
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 1
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3029
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3285
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3669
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3797
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program has finished
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program is half way
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3029
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3285
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3669
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3797
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program is half way
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 4
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3029
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3285
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3669
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3797
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program has finished
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: program has finished
```

I am using the variable `self.program_remaining` to block from looping in each time when I pass on the statement. I want to get the value so I can then use them to search for the elements using the value from the array `prog_id`

Here is the list of elements for the `prog_id`:

```
>>> value 0 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3029
>>> value 1 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
>>> value 2 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3285
>>> value 3 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
>>> value 4 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
>>> value 5 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3669
>>> value 6 15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3797
```

Here is what I am try to achieve:

```
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3157
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3413
15:53:41 T:1468  NOTICE: 3541
```

Because of this, I am counting the value in each time when it pass on the statement and I only get the values `1`, `3` and `4` for the `elif start_time < current_time < stop_time:` so I want to use these value under the `if current_program_length >= 30:` but I have no idea how to do this when I have blocked the variable to stop them to getting to pass in each time.

Can you please tell me how I can count value under the `elif start_time < current_time < stop_time:` to output the value under the `if current_program_length >= 30:` so I could search the elements from the arrays using the value?

Comment: disclaimer i don't intent to provide an answer. i am just point a direction. if I were you I would create a pandas.DataFrame that I would slice (maybe using loc) and use the isin function ("program is half way" being kinda mistatement).

Comment: I think I don't need this `if self.program_remaining == True:`. Do you know how I could use `prog_id` with the value to get the strings using the index from the array?

Comment: @user3761625 There are 2 confusing statements in your question. What is your desired output exactly ? You have mentioned earlier in the question: `so I could get the results like this.` and later in the question `Here is what I am try to achieve:`. Is it the 2nd one ?